# What is Farquaad’s first name?

Tags: shrek

Or surname if Farquaad is his first?

I mean, in Mr Stink, the titular character’s real name is Lord Darlington. We can safely conclude that Darlington is his surname.

Comment: Lord... he wasn't really a nobleman, it was just his name - like Duke Ellington or Count Basey. Little known fact - Lord Farquad was a demon on the flugelhorn

Answer (score 29):

It isn't mentioned in any of the *films*, but according to [*Shrek: The Musical*](https://www.sdcjc.org/common/pdf/jco/shrek_script.pdf) his full name is **Maximus** Farquaad.

---

[image: transcription below]

> ACT TWO
> SCENE TWO
> *(TORTURE CHAMBER)*
>
> **FARQUAAD**: 494, 495, 496. Princess Fiona? I am Lord Farquaad. What do you think? No, You're right, too formal. 600! Fiona? Hi, Farquaad, but you can call me Maximus, as I've no doubt you will! Woof! No, too smutty

Comment: So is Grumpy’s surname Farquaad?